# Adding document to the launchpad

Tags: software

Is it possible to add a document like a pages document or a screenshot into my launchpad? If so how do I do that

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar - add a bunch of game .roms to my Games folder - and was told that Launchpad won't allow any item not ending in the application suffix of .app to appear, regardless of where you keep the file in question. So as far as I know there's no built-in or obvious way to accomplish adding any non-applications to the Launchpad.

Answer (score 1):

Open Automator and choose to make an app.

Add two Actions:

- Get Specified Finder Items
- Open Finder Items

Add as many documents as you want to the "Get Specified Finder Items" action.

Save to the Applications Folder.

Select it in Finder and choose Get Info.  You can paste any icon you want, into the icon field at the top-left.

Open Launchpad and you should see your new app. You can re-arrange with click-hold-drag.